# Open covering of $S^n$ by sets not containing antipodal points

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Given an $n$-dimensional sphere $S^n$ and an open cover such that none of the open sets contain antipodal points, does there exist a point on $S^n$ that belongs to at least $n+1$ open sets from the open cover?

This is true for $S^1$, and it seems to be true for $S^2$. I am not sure if the Lusternik–Schnirelmann theorem would be useful here. I do not know too much about this field, so perhaps this problem is trivial. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The fact that $\text{ls}(\Bbb{RP}^n) = n+1$ implies that you have at least $n+1$ open sets in your open cover, as each of your $U$'s in your cover give rise to $p(U)$, an open subset of $\Bbb{RP}^n$ whose inclusion is null-homotopic. You can probably strengthen this result (maybe you need $2n+2$ open sets, to account for the double cover? spitballing...) Not sure what else one can say, probably you need to say something about topological dimension.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true for $\mathbb{S}^3$.

Start with the central projection of 4-cube to $\mathbb{S}^3$.
Consider a covering with one set $U$ that contains all vertices and edges + one open set that is very close to the remaining 2- and 3-cells.
The multiplicity of this covering can be made to be 3.

All open sets except $U$ do not contain opposite points.
After a small perturbation, opposite points disappear in $U$.
Since the perturbation is small, the property remains valid for the remaining open set.

Comment: To clarify: you have one open set for *each* of the remaining 2- and 3-cells, correct?

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect yes

Comment: why doesn't this construction work for S^2 as well?

Comment: @alesia perturbation of 1-skeleton in 2-sphere does not remove opposite points.

Comment: hmm right thanks